# Bootstrap modal resizable and draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to convert my modal to resizable and draggable. I have tried possible solutions like .resizable and .draggable functions of jquery.

I have included

```
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>
```

for resizable function and

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

for draggable function. The moment i used these two .js scripts for draggable my other datetimepicker scripts stop working from

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>.
```

Also, after that also my modal is not draggable or resizable.

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.his_modal_style {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 5; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.his_modal_style-content {
   background-color: #fefefe ;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #888;
   width: 55%;
   overflow: auto;
}


/* The Close2 Button */
.his_close {
color: #aaaaaa ;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.his_close:hover,
.his_close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}




 <div id="his_modal" class="his_modal_style">
 <div class="his_modal_style-content">
 <span class="his_close">&times;</span>
 /*Modal content*/

 </div>
 </div>
```

I tried

```
     $('.his_modal_style-content').draggable({
     handle: ".modal-header"
     });
     $('#his_modal_style').draggable({
     handle: ".modal-header"
     });
```

and

```
     $('.his_modal_style-content').resizable({
     });
     $('#his_modal_style').resizable({
     });
```

I am expecting to modal to be draggable and resizable.

Image of all scripts included already:

[image: .]